# Set Wordpress system time back by 15 minutes (Using UTC+2 at the moment)

Tags: wordpress, datetime, time, timezone, strtotime

I would like to set back the time of my Wordpress site by 15 minutes. I am currently using the UTC+2 setting but I would need to set it at UTC+1:45. which obviously does not exist. Is there any code for the functions.php to make this possible?

Comment: Don't have an answer for you, but in general I think this is a bad idea.